# How can I add a pre-defined class object to a list?

Tags: python

I'm working on a Udemy project where we need to create a class for products with price, code, and quantity and then create an inventory class with a function to find the total price for all of the products. The products class seems to work fine, but I am really struggling to figure out how to add the objects to a list in the inventory class. Here is the code I have so far:

```
inventory = []

# Define a Product class. Objects should have 3 variables for price, code, and quantity
class Product:
    
    def __init__(self, price=0.00, code='aaaa', quantity=0):
        self.price = price
        self.code = code
        self.quantity = quantity
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Product({self.price!r}, {self.code!r}, {self.quantity!r})'
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f'The product code is: {self.code}'

# Define an inventory class and a function for calculating the total value of the inventory. 
class Inventory:    
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.products_list = []
    
    def add_product(self):
        self.products_list.append(Product(price, code, value))
        return self.products_list
        
    def total_value(self):
        return sum(product.price * product.quantity for product in self.products_list)

apple = Product(1.00, 'appl', 10)
orange = Product(1.50, 'orng', 10)
pear = Product(1.75, 'pear', 10)

def main():
    Inventory.add_product(apple)
    Inventory.add_product(orange)
    Inventory.add_product(pear)
    Inventory.total_value()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Here is the error I am getting:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-116-972361fa1b80> in <module>
      1 if __name__ == "__main__":
----> 2     main()

<ipython-input-115-b55f02143572> in main()
      1 def main():
----> 2     Inventory.add_product(apple)
      3     Inventory.add_product(orange)
      4     Inventory.add_product(pear)
      5     Inventory.total_value()

<ipython-input-111-bbbfc35f0b7e> in add_product(self)
     25 
     26     def add_product(self):
---> 27         self.products_list.append(Product(price, code, value))
     28         return self.products_list
     29 

AttributeError: 'Product' object has no attribute 'products_list'
```

The roadblock right now is in the add_product method. I have no idea how to append to the list. I've seen solutions online for user input Products, but I want to do it with pre-defined ones so in theory you could import from and export to an excel sheet for example. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see two major errors. The first one is confusion between class methods and instance methods. The second is confusion about dataflow.

Like a product, an inventory should be instanced: you might want to have separate inventories at separate warehouses, or on separate days. Thus, just like you create an instance of a `Product`:

```
apple = Product(1.00, 'appl', 10)
```

create an instance of an `Inventory`, and then add products to that — not to the `Inventory` class:

```
inventory = Inventory()
inventory.add_product(apple)
```

Instance methods like `add_product` must take an extra argument, which is conventionally named `self`, to represent the object receiving the method call. You are also passing a product to be added. This means the `add_product` method should take *two* arguments. And since you are already passing in a product such as `apple`, there is no need for `add_product` to construct another `Product` inside it:

```
def add_product(self, product):
    self.products_list.append(product)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This was my first question here and I appreciate the help.